# Enum Generic not allow typed enum

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a class that accepts a generic enum as one of it's parameters. However when I then go to pass in a specified enum type, it throws the error `Expected a value of type '(Enum?) => void', but got one of type '(GradeLevel?) => void'`.

My classes are:
Radio Group Presentable

```
class RadioGroupPresentable<T extends Enum> implements Presentable {
  final List<T> values;
  final T groupValue;
  void Function(T? value) onChanged;

  RadioGroupPresentable(this.values, this.groupValue, this.onChanged);
}
```

RadioGroup

```
class RadioGroup<T extends Enum> extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<T> _values;
  final T _groupValue;
  ValueChanged<T?> onChanged;

  RadioGroup(this._values, this._groupValue, this.onChanged, {super.key});

  RadioGroup.fromPresentable(RadioGroupPresentable<T> p): this(p.values, p.groupValue, p.onChanged);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("building radio grouo");
    return Column(
      children: _values.map((e) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(e.name),
          leading: Radio<T>(
            value: e,
            groupValue: _groupValue,
            onChanged: onChanged,
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Enum

```
enum GradeLevel {
  tenth, eleventh, twelfth
}
```

Presentable creation

```
RadioGroupPresentable(GradeLevel.values, GradeLevel.tenth, (value) {
  if (value != null) {
    gradeLevel.setValue(value, action: "Update Grade Level");
    _application.gradeLevel = value;
    print(value);
  }
})
```

View (where error occurs)

```
case RadioGroupPresentable<GradeLevel>:
  RadioGroupPresentable<GradeLevel> presentable = p as RadioGroupPresentable<GradeLevel>;
  RadioGroup widget = RadioGroup.fromPresentable(presentable);
  content.add(widget);
  break;
```

I have tried to make the class generic so it would accept any enum, however it crashes when I pass it an enum.

Comment: Are you sure that type inference is working as you expect? The error you're getting indicates that the `GradeLevel` type argument isn't propagating through all your object instantiations correctly, as something is expecting a function capable of taking any generic `Enum` rather than a `GradeLevel`.

Comment: It would help if you provided an isolated reproduction of the issue that we can try out. The code you've submitted depends on other code that you haven't.

Comment: @hacker1024 If something can take any generic Enum then it should be able to take GradeLevel as it's an enum. I understand the error. I do not understand why Dart cannot accept GradeLevel when it can accept any generic enum

Comment: I updated the code for RadioGroup as it's what's causing the error

Comment: Sorry, but you clearly do not understand the error. Hopefully my answer clears this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by this line:

```dart
RadioGroup widget = RadioGroup.fromPresentable(presentable);
```

Type inference is failing here, so this is being interpreted as `RadioGroup<Enum>.fromPresentable(presentable)` rather than `RadioGroup<GradeLevel>.fromPresentable(presentable)`.

When the `RadioGroup.fromPresentable` structure attempts to store the `onChanged` function, it finds a function that has the wrong type. It wants a function that is capable of taking an argument of any `Enum` type, but the function it finds is only capable of taking arguments of the `GradeLevel` type.

Remember, a function is only a subtype of another if its argument types are **equally or more permissive** than its supertype.

```dart
(Enum value) {} is void Function(GradeLevel);
(GradeLevel value) {} is! void Function(Enum);
```

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean now. I fixed it by changing RadioGroup onValueChanged to accept (Enum value) and same for RadioGroupPresentable. Then in the Presenable Creation block I simply cast the enum to a GradeLevel

Comment: You should not be fighting the type system like that. You just need to use explicit typing. No casts are needed.